# Flexible text container to auto resize based on content

Tags: css

I am trying to create a banner here with the requirement that the title div with class bannerText should always appear at the center and must appear at center with a white background holding a padding of 30px between text and white background border.I want the banner text to be fluid with a maximum width of 900px.

So if there are few words, instead of staying fixed with 900px it must breakdown to the content with a padding of 30px with the whitish background.

But once the title get's longer it wraps to next line without expanding beyond 900px.

All the time the text should be aligned horizontally and vertically , which I have already done. But my problem is with the flexible container.

[image]

```css
#banner {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: anti-aliasing;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  max-height: 422px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#banner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.bannerText {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: -40px;
  color: #D87A00;
}
#bannerTitle {
  width: 911px;
  color: #0e2bff;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <section class="bannerImage">
    <img src="picture.png" class="img-responsive">
  </section>
  <div class="bannerText">
    <section id="bannerTitle">Demo banner title reset</section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't understand very well, but [is that what you want](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ru99b0yj/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#banner {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: anti-aliasing;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  max-height: 422px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bannerImage {
  height: 422px;
  background: orange;
}

.bannerText {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 900px;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: white;
}

#bannerTitle {
  padding: 30px;
  color: #0e2bff;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <section id="bannerImage">
  </section>
  <div class="bannerText">
    <section id="bannerTitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci !</section>
  </div>
</section>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EVPNGW)

Comment: Great! Exactly what I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is your friend! Don't make this more complicated than it has to be. Set your image as the background image of your banner. The only content in your banner is the title, so you only need the wrapper (the banner) and the content (the title). 2 divs with the properties you need. Use Flexbox to center your title, and set your max-width. Use rgba as your color to have the see-through effect.

CSS:

```
#banner {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background:#D60;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
}
.title {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  color:blue;
  padding:30px;
  max-width:840px;
}
```

HTML

```
<section id="banner">
  <div class="title">
  Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 
  </div>
</section>
```

The max-width comes from 900px - 60px of padding on each side.